# Android "remembers" shared preferences after complete app uninstall

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In my Android app I use a set of randomly generated file names to store some data. In order to ensure that the same set of file names are generated at app restart - and are yet different for each app installation - I start off the process by picking the names as substrings from a long string of random alphanumeric characters which I generate when the app is installed. This latter string is stored in Shared Prefereneces.

As I am testing out the app I have run into a rather peculiar issue.  From time-to-time I make major changes so I fully uninstall the app - and even Force Close it + clear all its data.  At that point I would expect that the device would have no "prior knowledge" of the app if it is reinstalled.  And yet I find that the Shared Preferences string is somehow "remembered".  This causes havoc if in the interim I have changed how the file name substrings are picked up from the stored shared preferences string.

How can I ensure that the app has "zero memory" of a previously installed version that has subsequently been uninstalled?

---

One solution I have used in the past is to instruct Android not to do any backups via the manifest file, `android:allowBackup = "false"`. However, I have backed away from that idea since - unless I am mistaken - it effectively means that I am stopping the user from porting their app over to a new device when they decide to change handsets.

Comment: We had same issue and get resolved by `android:allowBackup="false"` in `AndroidManifest.xml.` now try it with new device, it should have resolved. I have no idea how it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have changed my question a bit. I had tried the `android:allowBackup` approach but find that it can raise other issues as I explain now.

Comment: I just saw these comments and your updated question. I'll revise my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On (re)install, your app may be restoring files from Google auto-backup (via Google Drive). To disable this feature, you can explicitly set it to false in the manifest:

```
<manifest ... >
    ...
    <application android:allowBackup="false" ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

If you'd like more granular control over what is backed up/restored and what is not, you can include or exclude specific files from the backups.

See auto backup documentation:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#EnablingAutoBackup

If you don't want to disable auto backups, but want to reinstall with a "clean slate" (for testing purposes), you can do one of the following:

- Clear app data *after* reinstall. This will wipe out files that were restored automatically on install
- Clear app data *prior* to uninstall, then force a new backup (so old one gets reset) by using this command: `adb shell bmgr backupnow <PACKAGE>`

See how to test backups documentation:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/testingbackup#TestingBackup

Comment: I am accepting and upvoting your answer because you put me on the right track here.  I have provided my solution to the issue - based on what you suggested - as a separate answer for the benefit of others who might run into a similar situation.

Answer (score 2):

To extend on this, for example `mobile/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
    android:allowBackup="false">

    ...

</application>
```

Alike this one can disable auto-backup for debug builds - but keep it enabled for release builds.

Simply because disabling auto-backup for release builds might not be the intended outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @hungryghost's suggestion the I eventually implemented a solution

**Problem**:Shared preferences can be remembered by Android after app reinstall and blanket instructions in the manifest along the lines of `android:allowBackup = "false"` are not a solution.

So why not turn the problem into a solution on its own?  Here is what I do

- Check shared preferences for a build specific key.
- If that key is not found I do two things

  1. Clear out all shared preferences, `context.deleteSharedPrefernces(filename)`
  2. Now create that build specific key
  3. When I make app changes that require old preferences to be forgotten I simply change the build specific key.

Comment: `context.deleteSharedPreferences(filename)` could also be executed at the click of a button (here I have one fragment only accessible in debug builds, barely for test/debug related preferences).