# How to ask gradlew to uninstall app, before execution of test?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso, gradlew

I use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28076751/how-to-automatically-uninstall-android-app-from-device-before-installing-a-new-v/28077408), to configure my ***Android Studio***, to `uninstall` the previous app, before it executes the `Espresso` tests.

So, in `Run -> Edit Configurations -> Before launch` and then added the `:app:uninstallAll` so, when I run my testcase from AS, i only select the configuration, and it works well.

[image]

I use the `./gradlew connectedAndroidTest` to execute the Espresso test from command line. But, I am wondering,

How may i ask the commandline of gradle to uninstall the previous version, before execution of test?

Answer (score 1):

You can use adb to uninstall previous version example:

## unistall old apk

```
adb -s $device uninstall ${packageName}.debug
```

## uninstall test

```
adb -s $device uninstall "com.bookings.test"
```

device - connected device
packageName - package name of the app.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

you cannot ask the command-line of Gradle - but Gradle can ask the command-line prompt.

based upon this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713579/android-studio-clear-application-data-for-instrumentation-test/35157119#35157119), one can easily create the desired application uninstall `Exec` task:

```
task uninstallApp(type: Exec) {
    def uninstallCommand = ['adb', 'shell', 'pm', 'uninstall', 'com.acme.coyote']
    commandLine uninstallCommand
}
```

this task can be added, either with `task.finalizedBy` or with `task.dependsOn`.

also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53348625/549372) of mine, which explains how to deal with shared preferences ...

because when these preferences are being restored from backup; it's no fresh install.