# AAPT: error: '' is incompatible with attribute fullBackupContent (attr) reference|boolean

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting this error while building my app

ERROR:C:\Users\soama\Downloads\Compressed\VeeChat-master\VeeChat-master\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:27: AAPT: error: '' is incompatible with attribute fullBackupContent (attr) reference|boolean.

here is the file with the error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dev.spak.spakchatter"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="23"
        android:targetSdkVersion="31" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Although the *SdkVersion is captured in gradle build files, this is required for non gradle builds -->
    <!-- <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" /> -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" /> <!-- Required by older versions of Google Play services to create IID tokens -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.dev.spak.spakchatter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.dev.spak.spakchatter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.dev.spak.spakchatter.VeeChat"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:extractNativeLibs="false"
        android:fullBackupContent=""
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <service
            android:name="com.dev.spak.spakchatter.FirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name="com.dev.spak.spakchatter.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.dev.spak.spakchatter.StartActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.dev.spak.spakchatter.RegisterActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="com.dev.spak.spakchatter.StartActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.dev.spak.spakchatter.LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.dev.spak.spakchatter.SettingsActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.dev.spak.spakchatter.StatusActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="com.dev.spak.spakchatter.SettingsActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.dev.spak.spakchatter.UsersActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="com.dev.spak.spakchatter.MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.dev.spak.spakchatter.ProfileActivity"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.quangviet.veechat_TARGET_NOTIFICATION" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.dev.spak.spakchatter.ChatActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="com.dev.spak.spakchatter.MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:permission="com.google.firebase.auth.api.gms.permission.LAUNCH_FEDERATED_SIGN_IN"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <!--
             FirebaseMessagingService performs security checks at runtime,
             no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true"
        -->
        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService"
            android:directBootAware="true"
            android:exported="false" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.firestore.FirestoreRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="com.dev.spak.spakchatter" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!--
             FirebaseInstanceIdService performs security checks at runtime,
             no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true"
        -->
        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="-500" >
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <provider
            android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
            android:authorities="com.dev.spak.spakchatter.firebaseinitprovider"
            android:directBootAware="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:initOrder="100" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd either have to:

- set this property: `android:fullBackupContent="true"`.
- or reference an XML file, with a backup configuration.
- or remove the line altogether.

---

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53348625/549372) answer of mine, which shows how not to backup from debug builds.